# Second Normal Form of a Relational Database

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, relation

Afternoon Everyone,

I am currently attempting a database design revolving around the storing of records relating to the users physical activities.

One issue I am encountering is the storing of "User Details", at current the table holds values relating to user ID (PK), username (PK), password, email, weight, height and age.

Due to Weight, height and age possibly repeating with multiple users I am attempting to normalize the table, however I am encountering issues as even if the attributes acquire there own tables OR share a table, I will still have repeating, and thus redundant data, due to age, height or weight being repeated.

If anyone has any tabling recommendations to resolve this issue they would be most welcome.

Thanks

JHB92

Comment: Simply put don't.  Each value is unique to the username and you will not have multiple weights, heights or ages for the same user unless you intend to take sampling over time.  An address for a user might be something you normalize.  I can't imagine normalizing weight height and age to be of value... I'm not sure why you would put it in a seperate table in the first place unless you're indicating a user could have multiple usernames, passwords, emails, weights heights and ages...

Comment: The only apparent problem with your User Details table is that you seem to have a composite key of UserId and UserName. My guess/expectation would be that UserId and UserName should both be candidate keys in their own right, i.e. each User must have a unique Id *and* a unique name. Is that what you intended? It isn't possible to give detailed advice on normalization problems without knowing what dependencies are supposed to be in force.